# Apache Flink Connector for Elasticsearch 7x

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, elasticsearch-7

I was using Flink 1.9.0 with flink-connector-elasticsearch6_2.11, but this cannot connect to ES 7x.

I looked at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-13025 and downloaded the snapshot - *flink-connector-elasticsearch7_2.12-1.10-SNAPSHOT.jar* - locally and with *flink-connector-elasticsearch-base_2.11-1.9.1* can now connect to ES7.

Is this still in dev and hence not released to maven central yet? Any idea regarding the release date?

Answer (score 2):

An updated Elasticsearch connector that supports ES7 is part of Flink 1.10, which was recently released.

Comment: Is the ES7 connector officially released yet?

Comment: Yes, it has been released.

Answer (score 1):

***flink-connector-elasticsearch7***

For Flink Elasticsearch Connector I have used the following dependencies and versions mentioned below.

- Flink: 1.10.0
- ElasticSearch: 7.6.2
- flink-connector-elasticsearch7
- Scala: 2.12.11
- SBT: 1.2.8
- Java: 11.0.4

*Please find a detailed answer which I have provided* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61643158/7317816).